# How can I add child fragments to a fragment in Android using a BaseAdapter

Tags: java, android, listview, android-fragments, baseadapter

[image: Diagram of Hierarchical View consisting of Android Activity with Fragments]

This diagram illustrates the complexity of my activity. There are multiple (3 in this case) layers of fragments that need to load dynamically. The repeating fragments are loaded using LinearListView, a view library I found here: https://github.com/frankiesardo/LinearListView. This allows the list to load like a ListView, but avoids the problems of having a ListView inside a ScrollView.

Here is some of the sample code:

line_item_list.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/line_item_list">

  <TextView
    android:layout_width="171dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="LineItem List"
    android:id="@+id/line_item_list_text" />

  <com.linearlistview.LinearListView
    android:id="@+id/line_item_wrapper"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:divider="#f00"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:showDividers="middle"
    app:dividerThickness="16dp"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/tools"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

line_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/line_item">

  <TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="my line item."
    android:id="@+id/line_item_text"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

  <!-- notes child items go here -->

</LinearLayout>
```

LineItemFragment.java loads the fragment with an adapter (lineItem in this code is displayed with the word, "Part" in the illustration above.)

```
public class LineItemFragment extends Fragment {
  LineItemAdapter adapter;

  @Override
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {


    LinearListView lineItems = (LinearListView)container.findViewById(R.id.line_item_wrapper);
    adapter = new LineItemAdapter(this.getContext(), getChildFragmentManager());
    lineItems.setAdapter(adapter);

    return null;

  }
}
```

LineItemAdapter.java

```
public class LineItemAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

  ArrayList<String> lineItems = new ArrayList<String>();
  Context context;
  FragmentManager fm;


  public LineItemAdapter(Context context, FragmentManager fragmentManager) {
    this.context = context;
    lineItems.add("Item A");
    lineItems.add("Item B");
    lineItems.add("Item C");
    this.fm = fragmentManager;
  }

  @Override
  public int getCount() {
    return lineItems.size();
  }

  @Override
  public Object getItem(int position) {
    return lineItems.get(position);
  }

  @Override
  public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
  }

  @Override
  public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = ((LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE))
                .inflate(R.layout.line_item, parent, false);
    }
        ((TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.line_item_text)).setText(getItem(position).toString());


    // *** The getView method could load the child fragments
    return convertView;
  }
}
```

In this previous file (***), I am currently thinking the getView method should load the next level child fragment, but everything I have tried has not worked. It appears that the layout is not yet inflated, and so I cannot add child views to it.

My question is, "how do i add child fragments from within the getView?" Or maybe I am going about this wrong.

Here is one example of what I have tried:

getView Method (***) in lineItemAdapter.java:

```
.
.
.

    LinearLayout notes = (LinearLayout) ((LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE))
            .inflate(R.layout.line_item, parent, false);

    LinearLayout b = (LinearLayout)((LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE))
            .inflate(R.layout.note_list, notes).getRootView();

    NoteListFragment noteListFragment = new NoteListFragment();
    fm.beginTransaction().add(b.getId(), noteListFragment).commit();
.
.
.
```

And I got an exception like this.

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main

Process: com.example.myapplication, PID: 12207

java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity   
ComponentInfo{com.example.myapplication/com.example.myapplication.DetailActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment does not have a view
                                                                            at 
android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
                                                                            at   
android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
.
.
.
```

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

Do I need to add a fragment to the xml, i.e.:

line_item.xml...new node:

```
<fragment android:name="com.example.noteListFragment"
          android:id="@+id/note_list_fragment"
          android:layout_weight="1"
          android:layout_width="0dp"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Comment: You cant add fragments within `getView()` which belongs to a Fragment. You create an add a fragment from your Activity.

Comment: Check this answer also http://stackoverflow.com/a/13221546/423980

Comment: Appreciate the quick responses. Helpful, but how would you address the complexity of multiple layers requesting fragments from the activity? Would I be able to pass convertview to the method in the Activity without causing a memory leak so that the children could be added?

Comment: What I do in a case like that is I use an event bus library (like [Otto](http://square.github.io/otto/)  ). I have my Activity subscribed to events and when these happens you react accordingly (by replacing a fragment with another one).

Comment: Thanks @mt0s. I will give it a shot.

Comment: Sorry, but I need more clarification. Based on above, I would need access to a child fragment, but still don't see how that is created. Can you provide an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I moved away from fragments for this purpose, and removed the inflation code. Instead, I load up the same layout structure with includes in the xml, so I don't have to build larger xml files than I already have.

For the functionality I would have put in the fragments, I placed in presenter classes, then used view injection from ButterKnife to tie the presenter to the appropriate levels in the views.

I am still working on using an event bus to communicate between the layers like @mt0s suggested.

Here is some code to help you out if you want to go this direction:

Using includes I can bring the entire structure together, keeping each layer layout in its own xml file:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity_workorder"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
>
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/workorder_detail_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <include layout="@layout/workorder_header"/> <!-- include other layouts -->
        <include layout="@layout/workorder_service_items"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Next I created a Presenter.class file to set up the adapter, using ButterKnife to bind to that portion of the view:

```
public class WorkOrderPresenter implements PropertyChangeListener
{

    private View detailView;
    private WorkOrder workOrder; // the object to display
    private List<WorkorderAsset> assetList;

    // Set your bindings to the view, passing the id from the layout.
    @Bind(R.id.workorderasset_list) View serviceItemDetail;
    @Bind(R.id.workorderasset_list_content) LinearListView assets;
    @Bind(R.id.number_of_service_items) TextView numberOfServiceItems;
    @Bind(R.id.total_value) TextView totalView;

    WorkOrderAssetAdapter workOrderAssetAdapter; // an adapter for a child list

    // Constructor
    public WorkOrderPresenter(View view, WorkOrder wo, final Activity activity)
    {
        workOrder = wo;
        detailView = view;
        ButterKnife.bind(this, detailView); //this is where the binding actually happens

        workOrderAssetContent = Provider.GetItems // Load you items for the adapter.

        // My system gives items back asynchronously:
        workOrderAssetContent.getWorkOrderAssets(workOrder.getWorkOrderID(), new iProvideCallback<List<WorkorderAsset>>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(iResponse<List<WorkorderAsset>> response) {
                assetList = response.getResponse();
                numberOfServiceItems.setText(String.valueOf(assetList.size()));
                workOrderAssetAdapter = new WorkOrderAssetAdapter(activity, assetList); // construct the adapter with items.
                assets.setAdapter(workOrderAssetAdapter);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(iResponse<List<WorkorderAsset>> response) {
                Toast.makeText(activity.getApplicationContext(), R.string.ServiceItemsError, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);

            }
        });
    }
}
```

And here is an adapter to display the items:

```
public class WorkOrderAssetAdapter extends BaseAdapter
{
    private Activity activity;
    private List<WorkorderAsset> workorderAssetList;
    private static LayoutInflater inflater = null;

    // Constructor
    public WorkOrderAssetAdapter(Activity a, List<WorkorderAsset> items)
    {
        workorderAssetList = items;
        activity = a;
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(activity);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() { return workorderAssetList.size(); }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) { return workorderAssetList.get(position); }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) { return position; }

    // view holder for the item
    public static class ViewHolder extends WorkOrderAssetViewHolder
    {
        @Bind(R.id.line_item_text) TextView line_item_text;
        @Bind(R.id.line_item_list) LinearListView list;

        // Adapter, Data Provider and Presenter for the next level.
        public WorkOrderAssetLineItemAdapter adapter;
        public WorkOrderAssetLineItemProvider provider;
        public WorkOrderAssetLineItemPresenter presenter;

        private Activity activity;
        private WorkorderAsset workOrderAsset;

        public VehicleViewHolder(WorkorderAsset asset, final View view, Activity activity_in)
        {
            ButterKnife.bind(this, view);
            workOrderAsset = asset;
            activity = activity_in;
            workOrderAssetLineItemContent = new WorkOrderAssetLineItemContent(((RoadFS)activity.getApplication()).getServer(), ((RoadFS)activity.getApplication()).getApplicationContext());
            workOrderAssetLineItemContent.getWorkOrderAssetLineItems(
                    workOrderAsset.getWorkOrderID(),
                    workOrderAsset.getWorkOrderAssetID(),
                    new iProvideCallback<List<WorkorderAssetLineItem>>() {

                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(iResponse response) {
                            list.setAdapter(new WorkOrderAssetLineItemAdapter(activity,
                                    (List<WorkorderAssetLineItem>) response.getResponse(),
                                    view));
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(iResponse response) {

                        }
                    });

        }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View view, ViewGroup parent)
    {

        WorkorderAsset workOrderAsset;
        workOrderAsset = workorderAssetList.get(position);
        ViewHolder holder;
        if (view != null) {
            holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        } else {
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.workorder_detail_workorderasset_vehicle, parent, false);
            holder = new VehicleViewHolder(workOrderAsset, view, activity);
            view.setTag(holder);
        }

        holder.item_text.setText(workOrderAsset.getVIN());

        holder.workOrderAssetLineItemContent = new WorkOrderAssetLineItemContent(((RoadFS) activity.getApplication()).getServer(), activity);
        holder.workOrderAssetLineItemAdapter = new WorkOrderAssetLineItemAdapter(activity, WorkOrderAssetLineItemContent.workorderAssetLineItemList, view);

        return view;
    }
}
```

This example is a little incomplete, and I don't yet have a sample project, but hopefully it will help someone out. It doesn't answer the question as expected, but having tried both ways, I think it is a better solution because it is simpler than dealing with the complexities of fragments. Fragments will still be used for changing screen size/orientation, but fragments will not be used for the complex layout. Thanks for any input.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use different class for adapter

   ```
   public class TabCategory extends Fragment {
       private ListView listView;
       @Override
       public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
           super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       }
       @Override
       public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,   Bundle savedInstanceState) {
           // Inflate the layout for this fragment
           View tabCat=inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_all, container, false);
           listView = (ListView) tabCat.findViewById(R.id.listView);
           //ADAPTER
           CategoryList adapter = new CategoryList(getContext());
           listView.setAdapter(adapter);
           return tabCat;
       }
   }
   ```