# Replacing a fragment from inside a fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I read online, that to call another fragment, to take up the FrameLayout, you need to create an interface that talks to the activity and when the button clicked the function inside the interface that is defined in the activity replaces the Fragment with another fragment, but instead of creating the interface, i tried doing it directly from inside the fragment and it worked. So any reasons why i should not be doing this ?

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;

public class FragmentOne extends Fragment {


    public FragmentOne() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fragment_one, container, false);

        Button btnONe = view.findViewById(R.id.btnOne);
        btnONe.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                onButtonPressed();
            }
        });

        return view;
    }

    public void onButtonPressed() {

        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragmentContainer, new FragmentTwo("Femin Dharamshi did it!"));
        fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fragments are part of the Activity and fragment should be hosted through their parent activities as stated by google in Android developers docs.
 You can refer this link:-
https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating

Answer (score 0):

You should call  `getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(int id, Fragment fr).commit();`  in `onViewCreated()` method, not `onCreateView()` method.

Just move your code in `onCreateView()` into `onViewCreated()` method.